# How can the Single data type hold more than Long?

Tags: excel, types, vba

I was reading about how much memory data types take up, and [Microsoft says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/data-type-summary) that both Single and Long use 4 bytes. However, Single has a range of

> -3.402823E38 to -1.401298E-45 for negative values; 1.401298E-45 to 3.402823E38 for positive values

and Long has a range of

> -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

These are mindboggling differences, especially when it seems that Single should hold *less* than Long seeing as it can have decimals. This is not at all the case and it can in fact hold like 30 more digits??? I tried to find some information on this by myself but I had trouble finding anything relevant. If anyone has links or can explain it then I'd appreciate it a lot, thanks!

P.S. If this is not where I should post this, please let me know where I should and I will delete it here

Comment: When you see **Single** you are probably thinking *single byte*; in fact it is short for **[Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long` is an integer type.

`single` is a floating point type, which trades precision for a higher range.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. I didn't think about googling floating-point, which would have made finding this answer much easier. Thanks!